determine dart and flutter sdk version from compiled app android/windows
Hello i need to determine the exact dart and flutter SDK version that was used in a release compiled windows/android build.
In the windows build flutter_windows.dll does not have any file version metadata.

For Android, you can use an app called Flutter Shark, which provides the exact Flutter version, Dart version, and the channel the app was built with. Additionally, it lists all the packages used in the app.
However, I haven't found a similar method for determining the Flutter version from a compiled Windows app.

that's a nice tool for android thanks.
